# Add string prefix to automapped model property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I have 2 models - modelA and modelB:

```
    public class modelA {
        public string modelType { get; set; }

        [Column("next_number")]
        public int mNum { get; set; }
    }

    public class modelB {
        public string mNum { get; set; }

        //other properties
    }
```

The value of modelB.mNum is "A" + modelA.mNum. What I am currently doing is this:

```
    ModelA modelA = db.modelA.Where(a => a.modelType == "A").Single();
    modelB.nNum = "A" + modelA.mNum;
    db.modelBs.Add(modelB);
```

Is there a way that I could use Automapper to map the models and add the prefix in the model class? Or is this already good practice?

Note: I really do not approve this design, but I do not have the option to change it.
I initially thought that a trigger was responsible for adding the prefix, but it turns out, the desktop application was the one adding the prefix and incrementing next_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>().
    ForMember(mB => mB.mNum, o => o.MapFrom(mA => "A" + mA.mNum));
```

and then:

```
ModelA modelA = db.modelA.Where(a => a.modelType == "A").Single();
modelB = Mapper.Map<ModelA>(modelA);
db.modelBs.Add(modelB);
```

is this what you needed?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Can I put an if-else in the MapFrom function? I just realized that I need to put "A0" if mNum is 4 digits and only "A" if mNum is 5 digits.

Comment: @janinaj yes you can...it'll go inside the `MapFrom` expression

Comment: Thank you! I found a better alternative to the if-else statement I was thinking. I used `PadLeft`.